# "En el fil" - what does it mean?

Tags: gramática, expresiones, significado

What does the expression "en el fil" mean? For example as used this way:

> Muchos hombres trabajan en la agricultura, en el fil, deshierbando, podando y regando...

Comment: Most likely is the word  `field`, pronounced in a different way to mean its equvalent Spanish word `campo`

Comment: Where did you find this text? [edit] the question to show this info, so we have some context.

Comment: Funnily enough, in Spanish there is a most unused expression ["estar en fil" or "estar en un fil"](https://dle.rae.es/fil), used to denote the equilibrium some things have. Hence you can say "la balanza está en fil". Nonetheless, it most likely is the English word "field" but written as we would sloppily pronounce it in Spanish.

Comment: It would be useful to indicate if this refers to Mexican field workers in the US. That would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I copied and pasted "Muchos hombres trabajan en la agricultura, en el fil, deshierbando, podando y regando..." to Google translate.

Here is the translation Google translate gives:

Many men work in agriculture, in the fields, weeding, pruning and watering ...

ipp's comment is confirmed.
Charlie's comment is confirmed.

fil = field